# Are comments necessary for evaluating tag relevance?

Tags: discussion

I thought that https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9580954 was an irrelevant tag edit, because the (IMHO quite poor) question did not mention java. So I rejected it. Afterwards I looked at the question and saw that it was stated in the comments (which were not shown during the review) that this was a java question.

Should this edit have added the tag also somewhere in the questions body? Is it ok to consider a tag as irrelevant if it appears only in comments or are the comments required to determine the relevance? In the latter cases I think comments need to be shown in reviews.

Comment: Truthfully, that edit doesn't matter: The question will be pruned soon enough. And the edit-comment given is absolutely useless.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think comments are necessary on the review page. They're not needed most of the time, and there is a link to the entire post if you can't decide if a suggested edit is valid.

In this case, the tag edit was borderline. It *does* add information to the post, so it is an improvement, but it's not nearly enough to salvage the question. The OP really needs to show their code and explain in more detail before anyone can tell them what they've done wrong (short of writing an answer that starts from scratch and gives a complete solution). I'd reject the edit and vote to close the question, but I wouldn't tell someone they were *wrong* for accepting the edit and voting to close the question.

Comment: Ok, this means that comments may be relevant, but the small percentage where this is really the case does not justify to show them on the review page. I guess for "irrelevant tags" it is the case more often than for other causes, so I guess I will have a closer look if the question deserves it (which was obviously not the case here),